# Not getting a map in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, geospatial, folium

I am trying to create a map for "Ecuador" country with the coordinates 1.8312° S, 78.1834° W in Folium map using the below code

```
map = folium.Map(location=[1.8312, 78.1834], zoom_start=12)
map
```

The map is not appearing and getting below empty output

[image]

When I tried for another country example: US, I am getting an output. Not sure why I am not getting for Ecuador. I am using Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you used (1.8312, 78.1834) refer to south and west. Folium [needs north and east](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.map).

Therefore, use:

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[-0.22985, -78.52495], zoom_start=12)

m
```

and you get your map:

[image]